# Difference in string arrays in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to determine the difference between 2 string arrays in BigQuery using Standard SQL.

For example, say:

```
id    cust_id    orders     high_value_orders
1     1          [a,b,c,d]    [a,b]
```

What I'd like to do is to get:

```
id    cust_id    diff
1     1          [c,d]
```

Basically performing the set operation `orders - high_value_orders`.

I've tried a couple things, and I know it probably needs UNNEST, but I'm not sure how to exactly write it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT element FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT element FROM t.orders element UNION ALL
      SELECT DISTINCT element FROM t.high_value_orders element 
    )
    GROUP BY element
    HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
  ) AS diff
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

If to apply to you sample data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 cust_id, ['a','b','c','d'] orders, ['a','b'] high_value_orders
)
SELECT *,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT element FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT element FROM t.orders element UNION ALL
      SELECT DISTINCT element FROM t.high_value_orders element 
    )
    GROUP BY element
    HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
  ) AS diff
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

result is

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail Berlyant!